# how to make d3js donut chart supports ie8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, d3.js

I found d3js donut chart to be very good for my needs.
the only problem for me is that it doesnt support IE8.

Is there any way to use d3js donut chart in IE8?

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'map' 
d3.v3.min.js, line 3 character 17383
```

I know d3js supports only IE8+ browsers. I wonder if there is a workaround only for this case.
if not, can you recommand a js library with the same license agreement (BSD) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this already using r2d3.js library.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [flot.js](http://www.flotcharts.org/)? The [donut chart syntax](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html) is pretty simple, it has a [MIT licence](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/LICENSE.txt), and supports earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use highcharts your problem will be solved.

Look at below url:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut